# Slicing a list with a stepsize

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've searched all around but didn't find a simple answer.

How can I slice a list in Common Lisp with a given `step` without resorting to a `loop`?
It seems odd that `subseq` won't take a third parameter, i.e., `(subseq lst start end step)`.

Python equivalent:

```
 lst[start:end:step]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing similar in the standard CL. One could use `REDUCE` or `DO` to implement it. I would just use `LOOP`:

Helper function:

```
(defun %take (it what)
  (cond ((eq what :all) it)
        ((eq what :none) nil)
        ((and (numberp what) (plusp what))
         (subseq it 0 what))
        ((and (numberp what) (minusp what))
         (last it (- what)))
        ((and (consp what)
              (= (length what) 1)
              (numberp (first what)))
         (nth (first what) it))
        ((and (consp what)
              (= (length what) 2)
              (numberp (first what))              
              (numberp (second what)))
         (let ((end (if (minusp (second what))
                        (+ (length it) (second what))
                      (second what))))
           (subseq it (first what) end)))
        ((and (consp what)
              (= (length what) 3)
              (numberp (first what))
              (numberp (second what))
              (numberp (third what)))
         (let ((start (first what))
               (end (if (minusp (second what))
                        (+ (length it) (second what))
                      (second what)))
               (by-step (third what)))
           (loop for e = (subseq it start) then (nthcdr by-step e)
                 for i from start below end by by-step
                 collect (first e))))))
```

`TAKE`:

```
(defun take (thing &rest description)
  "Taking things from lists like in Mathematica
Description is one or more of:
   :all | :none | [sign]number | ( start [end [step]])"
  (cond ((null description) nil)
        ((and (consp description)
              (= (length description) 1))
         (%take thing (first description)))
        (t (loop for e in (%take thing (first description))
                 collect (apply #'take e (rest description))))))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 27 > (take '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11) '(2 7 2))
(2 4 6)

CL-USER 28 > (defun sublist (list start end step)
               (take list (list start end step)))
SUBLIST

CL-USER 29 > (sublist '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11) 2 7 2)
(2 4 6)
```